# Creating an ActionLink with a DateTime in the query string in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a search form with a DateTime search criterion, plus some other criteria:

```
<form method="get" action="/app/search">
    <input type="text" value="13/01/2010" name="BeginDate"/>
    <input type="text" value="blah" name="SomeOtherCriterion"/>
<form>
```

So I have a Search controller with a default Action (let's call it Index) and with a SearchCriteria parameter.

```
public class SearchController
{
    public ActionResult Index(SearchCriteria searchCriteria) {//blah }
}    

public class SearchCriteria
{
    public DateTime BeginDate {get; set;}
    public string SomeOtherCriterion {get; set;}
}
```

Now if I want to create an ActionLink, passing in a SearchCriteria value, thus:

```
Html.ActionLink("Search", "Index", searchCriteria)
```

I get the BeginDate query string parameter in US format.  Looking on Google and poking around in System.Web.Routing using Reflector it seems to be because it uses the InvariantCulture, so there's nothing I can do about it.

It seems like noone has asked this question before so I guess I'm doing something very stupid....  Please help!

EDIT: Pass in SearchCriteria to ActionLink rather than anonymous object to show why I can't just do the custom ToString() myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that the framework appears to be hard-coded to handle this piece of data using InvariantCulture, I don't think there's much you can do to make it work transparently.

There is one ugly option - download the MVC source and rip out the code for all the offending classes from `Route` down to `ParsedRoute` to create your own `RouteBase` implementation that does what you need.

If I absolutely *had* to keep the DateTime declaration on the `SearchCriteria` class, then that's the route (sorry for the pun) I would choose.

However, a far easier solution would be to change your SearchCriteria class to use a slightly different declaration for the DateTime field, based on a type like this:

```
public class MyDateTime
{
  public DateTime Value { get; set; }
  //for passing MyDateTime in place of a DateTime without casting
  public static implicit operator DateTime(MyDateTime instance) { return instance.Value; }
  //so you can assign a MyDateTime from a DateTime without a cast
  //- e.g. MyDateTime dt = DateTime.Now
  public static implicit operator MyDateTime(DateTime instance) { return new MyDateTime() { Value = instance }; }
  //override ToString so that CultureInfo.CurrentCulture is used correctly.
  public override string ToString()
  {
    return Value.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture);
  }
}
```

In theory you should be able to roll out this change without too much fuss.

The big work could be if you have a lot of code that uses members (e.g. .Days etc) of the DateTime instance in SearchCriteria: you either have to reproduce those members on `MyDateTime`, wrapping around the inner `DateTime Value` or change all the code to use `.Value.Member`.

Comment: Not really practical for us but definitely the most inventive solution so I will accept it.  Thanks Zoltan.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid issues related to Regional Settings and "Culture",
I treat date and time as separate unbound fields and then
assemble them into DateTime in my Controller.

Example:

`Year [    ]    Month [    ]    Day  [    ]`

I always present separate textboxes for year, month, and day, in that order so that there can be no confusion between U.S. format (month/day/year) and more or less the rest of the world's format (day/month/year).

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide a formatted date in your ActionLink?  Try this:

```
Html.ActionLink("Search", 
                "Index", 
                new {BeginDate = 
                      DateTime.Now.ToString("d", new CultureInfo("pt-BR");})
```

Of course this changes BeginDate to a string instead of a DateTime... but maybe that will work for you?

Comment: See edit.  I want to be able to just pass a SearchCriteria straight in rather than use an anonymous object.  I knew I was missing something from the question!

Comment: Ah, that's a bit tougher.  I guess you could always anonymize the SearchCriteria just to format the date string, but that would be a huge pain...

Comment: Someone downvoted you womp.  Guess you don't care with 23000 points but it seemed harsh anyway.  I upvoted to compensate.

Answer (score 1):

We use ISO ("s" in a format string -- YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS) format for this. It works correctly, and JavaScript can handle it as well.

Comment: But how do you get ActionLink or any of the other MVC methods that use a RouteValueDictionary to convert a DateTime to this format?

Comment: Just put it in as a string: `new RouteValueDictionary(new { SomeDate = anotherDate.ToString("s") })`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use a [Model Binder](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Model_Binders_in_ASPNET_MVC.aspx) to format and parse the date?  Just re-read the article and noticed that it does not format the date...Probably not going to work out.  I'll leave the answer though in case it provides any unintentional inspiration :)

Comment: Thanks Chris.  AFAIK that's only good for handling requests coming in, doesn't help with creating a URL using ActionLink.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> poking around in System.Web.Routing using Reflector it
> ```
>
> seems to be because it uses the
>   InvariantCulture

Are you realy shure about this? The parts of Modelbinding and UrlBuilding I checked used CurrentCulture. Can you check what happens if you set the CurrentCulture before rendering the link?

Comment: The bit I'm looking at is System.Web.Routing.ParsedRoute.Bind.  Down at the bottom where it puts any "unused values" into the query string.  (Although every ToString in this method uses InvariantCulture.)

I tried setting CurrentCulture.  It doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Get the ASP.NET MVC 1.0 book written by Scott Hanselman, Scott Guthrie, Phil Haack, and Rob Conery. They actually do this exact scenario in the book. They use a specific route. I am looking at it right now on page 216.

They do it by breaking up day, month, and year. Then it is your responsibility to use those values as they come back.